# What's the Jacobian of the sign function for vectors?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, dirac-delta

What's the Jacobian of the sign function for vectors or:

$$A = \frac{\mathrm{d} \hat{v}}{\mathrm{d} \vec{v}}$$

I think it is probably some kind of dirac delta or something like:

$$A\vec{u} = 2\delta{\left\vert\vec{v}\right\rvert}\vec{u} $$

but I'm not sure. I think there should be some kind of cross product there but using the vector $\left(1, 1, 1\right)$ seems wrong to me.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: What's the sign function for vectors? I know it for numbers. Does it just take the sign of each vector component to make a vector of $\pm 1$'s?

Comment: @jdods I just mean finding the direction the vector points or $\vec{v} / \left\lvert \vec{v} \right\rvert$.

Comment: I would call that the "normalization" function. Now is the vector $v=(x,y,z)$ or is it some vector field with scalar function components?

Comment: $A=\frac{I-\hat{v}\hat{v}^T}{\|v\|}=\frac{v^TvI-vv^T}{(v^Tv)^{3/2}} \,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 2):

Let ${\hat v}$ denote a unit vector, and let ${\vec v}$ denote a vector in the direction of ${\hat v}$ but with variable length $\lambda$.

Find the differential of ${\vec v}$ 
$$\eqalign{
  {\vec v} &= \lambda\,{\hat v} \cr
 d{\vec v} &= {\hat v}\,d\lambda + \lambda\,d{\hat v} \cr
 d{\hat v} &= \frac{d{\vec v} - {\hat v}\,d\lambda}{\lambda} \cr
  &= \frac{\lambda^2d{\vec v} - {\vec v}\lambda\,d\lambda}{\lambda^3} \cr
}$$
We also have the relation
$$\eqalign{
  \lambda^2 &= {\vec v}^T{\vec v} \cr
   \lambda\,d\lambda &= {\vec v}^Td{\vec v} \cr\cr
}$$
Substituting this into the previous result yields
$$\eqalign{
 d{\hat v} &= \frac{\lambda^2Id{\vec v} - {\vec v}{\vec v}^Td{\vec v}}{\lambda^3} \cr
\frac{d{\hat v}}{d{\vec v}} &= \frac{\lambda^2I - {\vec v}{\vec v}^T}{\lambda^3} \cr 
&= \frac{I - {\hat v}{\hat v}^T}{\lambda} \cr}$$

Comment: By $\hat{v}hat{v}^T$ what do you mean? $\hat{v}^T$ means a tangent vector right? Shouldn't a tangent vector times a vector either be zero or $\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2$ depending on if it is the dot product or cross product? I guess one way you can lift a vector to a matrix is by using its cross product like $f\left(\vec{v}\right)\vec{u} = \vec{v} \times \vec{u}$ and so you could have $f\left(\vec{v}\right) f\left(\vec{v}\right)$ but I am uncertain what you mean.

Comment: The superscript T denotes the transpose operation.  So $x^Ty$ is the inner (aka dot) product of 2 vectors, while $xy^T$ is the outer (aka dyadic) product. The notation is common in matrix analysis, but probably not so common in vector analysis.